# Where can i find CiviCRM volunteers?

Tags: civivolunteer

I'm volunteering for a new non-profit that has very limited resources and was wondering if there is any place that we can find volunteers for helping with CiviCRM. For finding FOSS developers i know about places such as idealist, sourceforge and openhatch, but what is the best place to find volunteers that are experts on CiviCRM specifically? (Doesn't have to be programmers)

Kind Regards, Tord

Answer (score 2):

You're probably best off recruiting for volunteers in general who are interested in volunteering in your sector, and offering that person the opportunity to upskill.

Good luck,

John